# Background Image on pseudo elements

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, background-image, pseudo-element, unify

I am trying to insert background images into each tab as per the screenshot below but because the arrow is created using pseduo elements I am not sure how to do it.

[image]

Please see below a snippet of where I am upto so far. The final product should look like the screenshot so I am just missing the images in the background. Be sure to view the snippet in expanded view.

I have tried setting a background image with a colour in front but that didnt work. I cant seem to figure it out for the life of me!

If anyone could help that would be greatly appreciated.

```css
/* CDCD HOMEPAGE */

.u-nav-v8-2 .nav-item:first-child .nav-link {
  padding: 35px 85px 35px 135px;
}

.u-nav-v8-2 .nav-link {
  padding: 35px 100px 35px 135px;
}

[class*="u-nav-v8"] .nav-link {
  background-color: #767577;
}

[class*="u-nav-v8"] .nav-link::after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #767577 0%, rgba(118, 117, 119, 1) 100%);
}

.u-nav-v8-2 .nav-link::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49.6%, #767577 50%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.6%, #767577 50%);
}

[class*="u-nav-v8"] .nav-link.active {
  background-color: #B81818;
}

[class*="u-nav-v8"] .nav-link:hover {
  background-color: #B81818;
}

[class*="u-nav-v8"] .nav-link:hover:after,
[class*="u-nav-v8"] .nav-link:hover:before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49.6%, #B81818 50%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.6%, #B81818 50%);
}

.u-nav-v8-2 .nav-link.active::before {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, transparent 49.6%, #B81818 50%), linear-gradient(to top left, transparent 49.6%, #B81818 50%);
}

[data-tabs-mobile-type="slide-up-down"] {
  padding-top: 0px;
}

[data-tabs-mobile-type="slide-up-down"] .nav-link {
  border: none;
  border-width: 0px;
  border-style: none !important;
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .u-nav-v8-2 .nav-item:first-child .nav-link {
    padding: 35px 85px 35px 85px;
  }
  .u-nav-v8-2 .nav-link {
    padding: 35px 100px 35px 85px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://impression.testcre8.co.uk/assets/css/unify-components.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://impression.testcre8.co.uk/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://impression.testcre8.co.uk/assets/css/unify-core.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://impression.testcre8.co.uk/assets/vendor/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<!-- CDCD -->

<ul class="nav nav-fill justify-content-center d-flex flex-wrap flex-lg-nowrap u-nav-v8-2" role="tablist" data-target="nav-8-2-primary-hor-center" data-tabs-mobile-type="slide-up-down" data-btn-classes="btn btn-md u-btn-primary btn-block">
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link active" href="/impression-visual-branding-services/visual-branding-consultancy/">
      <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Consult <i class="fas fa-arrow-right g-pos-rel g-ml-10 material-icons"></i></h2>
      <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Understanding your brief, campaign goals &amp; vision.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#creativeConcept">
      <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Design <i class="fas fa-arrow-right g-pos-rel g-ml-10 material-icons"></i></h2>
      <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Creative concepts that bring your brief to life.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#modeling3D">
      <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Create <i class="fas fa-arrow-right g-pos-rel g-ml-10 material-icons"></i></h2>
      <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Fully in-house, quality-assured production.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
  <li class="nav-item">
    <a class="nav-link" href="#happyClients">
      <h2 class="text-uppercase u-nav-v8__title g-color-white text-left g-mb-5">Deliver <i class="fas fa-arrow-right g-pos-rel g-ml-10 material-icons"></i></h2>
      <p class="u-nav-v8__description g-color-white introText text-left g-mb-0">Packing, dispatch &amp; on site installation management.</p>
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>

<!-- END CDCD -->
```

Answer (score 1):

In order for pseudo element to be visible you must provide `content` property, e.g. `content: '';` in your case. Also don't forget to setup width and height.

```
[class*="u-nav-v8"] .nav-link::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to left, #767577 0%, rgba(118, 117, 119, 1) 100%);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Vadim will this allow me to include an image behind the color as shown in the screenshot? At the moment it is just a solid color but I would like an image behind it.

Comment: @NathanClancy you can use any image as background, e.g. `background-image: url(my/image/path.png);`. Now you just have gradient as background, you can also set `background-color: transparent;` if you don't want any underlying color

Comment: Hi @Vadim. I am trying to put a image in the background of the arrow :before element but I can't figure this out. Am i doing something wrong? I tried adding both an image and the linear gradient but it didnt work.

Comment: @NathanClancy I was thinking you need a way to show background on pseudo element (:before or :after). Can you please explain in more detail what troubles you? In `background-image` you can put url to your image and it will fill that element

Comment: @NathanClancy I did a little js fiddle to you to show how would I make the arrow in the pic you provided https://jsfiddle.net/mh5jLb60/

Comment: Hi @ Vadim that's great thank you. Could you show me how you would put an image in the background including in the background of the arrow? Because the box and the arrow are separate elements I don't know how you would set a background image to run behind both. Does that make sense? Thanks.

Comment: @NathanClancy not sure how to have clipped background with css only (at least for most browsers), but you can achieve this with svg. I will show it here https://jsfiddle.net/ckbsavhp/. Please note that this is only demo and it is better to prepare svg as asset and use it as background, not absolutely positioned as in my demo.

You can also use css `clip-path` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path, but browser support is not good for this one. Better to use svg method.

Comment: Also if you do not like svg solution you may as well just prepare png background with background and image beneath it in photoshop and use it as background

Comment: Great we seem to be really close here. Your example works for the image in the background but only if the arrow block is on its own. How would you fit 4 together like in my screenshot and snippet?

Comment: @NathanClancy you will need to utilize `z-index` on items. Make sure the first item has z-index less than next, etc. I updated the example so you can see what I mean https://jsfiddle.net/p9cvrk8u/. I used flexbox to align my items, you don't have to use flexbox. The main idea is you add class to each item and set z-index to each of them in a way that each item has growing z-index

Comment: Its sorted! Thanks you for your help. I set the background colour as transparent and used images as mentioned. Thanks again!

Comment: Thank you, please consider making your question answered :)